# Filter tax_query by term starting with character

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to filter tax_query by term starting with some characters (i.e. STAxxxx) in WordPress WP_Query.

Suppose I have below information stored at WordPress Admin:
**Post Type:** product
**Taxonomy:** brand
**Terms available for brand:** Adidas, Reebok, Puma, Nike, Asics etc.

If user enters 'a' into brand textbox, brands starting with 'a' should populate.

I've tried below snippet but it didn't work:

```
'taxonomy' => 'brand',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => $brand_name_field, '%',
'operator' => 'LIKE'
```

Comment: Do to want to fetch the products or the brands when a user inputs 'a' into the brand textbox?  If you want to fetch the taxonomy brands you should not use `WP_Query` but `get_terms`. WP_Query is used to fetch the posts of a certain post type while get_terms is used to get all the terms of a certain taxonomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omar, I was on mini vacation hence couldn't reply to your answer. I am sorry for that.

None of your suggestions worked for me. Then I've researched on Stack overflow more and found a useful links that worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29994568/5196594

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the products without fetching the brands I have updated your code to the following (but please note that all brands containing 'a' in their name, not necessarily starts with an 'a' will be fetched):

```
'taxonomy' => 'brand',
'field' => 'name',
'terms' => $brand_name_field
'operator' => 'LIKE'
```

If starting with an 'a' is a must, I would suggest that you do the query after the user inputs at least 2 or 3 characters to reduce the possibility of fetching unnecessary brands.

---

If you want to get just the brands where the names starts with an 'a' you should not do `WP_Query`, you need to use `get_terms()` with the `name__like` argument set.

The following will do the trick:

```
$brands = get_terms([
  'taxonomy' => 'brand',
  'name__like' => 'a' //you can use a variable in your case $search
  'fields' => 'ids' //If you cant to fetch all term data use 'all'
]);
```

Please note that this will not fetch brands that start with 'a' but will fetch all brands that contain 'a' therefore Adidas, Puma and Asics will be fetched. This was changed in WordPress 3.7, when previously name__like matched terms that begin with the string.

If you want to also search for both term names and slugs you can use `search` instead of `name__like`

You can get more information here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/

---

After you fetch the brands you can also get all products that are categorised under those brands by doing the following `WP_Query` with `tax_query` as follows in case the one at the top does not solve your issue:

```
$products = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => [
      'taxonomy' => 'brand',
      'field' => 'term_id',
      'terms' => $brands,
      'operator' => 'IN'
    ]
]);
```

Let me know if this works for you.