# WordPress tax_query taxonomy starting with particular character

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have an listing page on my WordPress site which outputs many different post types in alphabetical order based on the title of the `topic` taxonomy.

For example I have `videos`, `pages`, `research`, `profile`, `abstract` post types which all share the global taxonomy of `topic`. Within `topic`, there are such terms as Asthma, Bone, Cancer, Diabetes, Epilepsy, Gout etc. On my A to Z listing page, there will be a category A which would need to display all `videos`, `pages`, `research`, `profile`, `abstract` which have a topic taxonomy beginning with A such as Asthma, then a category B with all post types containing a topic taxonomy such as Bone etc.

I have no idea how to achieve this. Googling hasn't helped. I have tried a few variations of the `tax_query` I can get all the post types outputting with their topic taxonomy listed but I can't come up with a way to only output topic taxonomies beginning with A etc. I can achieve this with post title but I can't get it to work within a `tax_query`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: An "A to Z" page is a little complicated in this regard. Depending on how much content you have, and/or if you need pagination on this page, it might just be better to grab all of the terms and deal with this in PHP. You can do this in native WordPress, however you'd need to use some [arguably ugly hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29994568/231316) which even I would personally avoid if at all possible.

Comment: If you want to display _all_ posts for A to Z on the same page - then you don't need any query that selects posts by topic staring with a specific letter. You simply need to select _all_ of them, properly sorted by topic - and then implement a _control break_ in your output logic.